# Rails 5: Why does jQuery work on js.erb files without $(document).ready but not with direct html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a home.html.erb on my main_pages with this:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#success").modal();
  });
</script>
```

However it will not work when I remove the `$(document).ready` function.

But on my home.js.erb, this would fire fine even without the `$(document).ready` function:

```
 $("#success").modal();
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because the document is not ready. Inline script tags are evaluated when they are parsed - at that point the element which they are targeting may not have been added to the DOM yet. If you move the script tag to the end of the document it will work.

Comment: @max oh ok! So its safe in the home.js.erb since its added at the end of script file. Thanks again!

Comment: No - the `js.erb` is loaded as an ajax request when the user clicks a link or submits a form. at the point the documents is almost certainly completely loaded and ready. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/